# Detecting windows shutdown event

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, shutdown, system-shutdown

I have a windows Service always running once PC started, how would i detect using .NET 3.5 or WMI, when the user or some other application/process has requested a shutdown or reboot in windows.

I do not want to stop it, just log the time and who initiated the shutdown (user or process is fine, don't really need to know which process)

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) event.

However, note that you are in a Windows Service, and this event won't fire for you unless you create a hidden form in your service. You can get one of these for free by enabling the "Interact with Desktop" option on the service.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [SystemEvents.SessionEnding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.sessionending.aspx) event.

> Occurs when the user is trying to log
>   off or shut down the system.

Answer (score 0):

Win32.SessionEnded event gets fired when the system is being shut down. You should attach to this in your program.