# Computer Shutdown event ? VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, shutdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting windows shutdown event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173825/detecting-windows-shutdown-event)

Is there is any event about shutting down in VB.NET ? I want to execute statement when the computer the user clicks shut down , can this be done in vb.net ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Example from [here](http://vbcity.com/forums/t/84431.aspx)

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        AddHandler Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.SessionEnding, _
               AddressOf Handler_SessionEnding
    End Sub

    Public Sub Handler_SessionEnding(ByVal sender As Object, _
               ByVal e As Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndingEventArgs)
        If e.Reason = Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndReasons.Logoff Then
            MessageBox.Show("User is logging off")
        ElseIf e.Reason = Microsoft.Win32.SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown Then
            MessageBox.Show("System is shutting down")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```