# How to make a C++ Program listen for system commands

Tags: c++, windows, listen

I was recently asked how/if possible that one could do this. I am not sure if it is even possible, and I have been searching on it for a while now.

Basically let's take `Windows` for example there is a system command to shut down the computer. Let's say `shutdown -s -t 30 -c "Shutdown"`

Is there a way to write a program which will listen for a `shutdown` command, and then run `shutdown -a` in response to abort that command?

In short, can you make it listen for certain system commands on the computer and execute system commands in response?

Comment: Windows has all sorts of messages it passes around. One is `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. When you get that you could proactively call `shutdown -a`. Check this page out for more details on API hooking http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed

Comment: Note that there's no `shutdown` **command** at Windows level. There is a Windows program `Shutdown.EXE`, which knows which fundamental Windows API to call. But it's not the only program which knows this. E.g. Explorer.EXE (responsible for the start menu) knows it as well. So detecting `shutdown.EXE` would not affect Explorer.EXE shutting down.

Answer (score 1):

This is indeed possible. Your example, however, is probably not the best one to describe a generic problem. There are session events in Windows that applications can listen to, and [shutdown is one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3173825/detecting-windows-shutdown-event). And after all, `shutdown.exe` is not the only application that can ask Windows to shut down.

In general, however, applications “listening” for commands being executed will have to integrate tightly with the operating system. You can imagine that anti-virus software does exactly that and a lot more in order to prevent execution of 
“bad” programs. I am not familiar with Windows technology but would imagine hooking the Windows system call that executes binaries is the way to do it. For sure that will require "administrative" permissions and can even require to write a kernel module.

Answer (score 1):

You can go this way:

1. Check if the program is exiting.
2. If yes, then cancel the program exit call and execute `system("shutdown -a);`
3. Else, do what you want.

Well, probably there many more sophisticated ways to do that. And I agree with @VladLazarenko's answer; programs like antiviruses keep listening to system commands. But I guess that would require in-depth knowledge of the API. This is just a simple way to do that. If you are not a newbie, then you must visit this link, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed (from @RedX's comment). Good Luck! :)